# for loop does not upload all images in Codeigniter3

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have website where I upload several photos at a time. In some moment I noticed that, it does not upload all required photos. Then I renamed photos from 1.jpg to 14.jpg in order to see, what does my code upload. It uploads only odd numbers (2.jpg, 4.jpg, 6.jpg ... 14.jpg). Where can be the problem?

```
public function addpic() {
            $manymanyimages = '';
            $config['upload_path'] = './assets/img/cars/';
            $config['allowed_types'] = 'jpg|png|jpeg|JPG|PNG|JPEG';
            $config['overwrite'] = FALSE;
            $config['remove_spaces'] = TRUE;
            $config['max_size'] = '25000';
            $this->load->library('upload', $config);
            $filesCount = count($_FILES['files']['name']);
            for ($i = 0; $i < $filesCount; $i++) {
                $_FILES['filee']['name'] = $_FILES['files']['name'][$i];
                $_FILES['filee']['type'] = $_FILES['files']['type'][$i];
                $_FILES['filee']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i];
                $_FILES['filee']['error'] = $_FILES['files']['error'][$i];
                $_FILES['filee']['size'] = $_FILES['files']['size'][$i];
                if (!$this->upload->do_upload('filee')) {
                    // $this->output->set_status_header(500);
                    $this->output->set_output(strip_tags($this->upload->display_errors()));
                } else {
                    $fileData = $this->upload->data();
                    $manyimages = $fileData['file_name'];
                }
            }

            $last_id = $this->db->select('id')->order_by('id',"desc")->limit(1)->get('cars')->row()->id + 1;

            $data = array(
                'img_name' => $manyimages,
                'iki' => $manymanyimages,
                'post_id' => $last_id
            );

            return $this->db->insert('imgs', $data);
        }
```

Comment: What you are getting in `$filesCount`?

Comment: in code? because if I upload 10 images it inserts only 5

Comment: @JavidAbbasov to count images you are using this code { $filesCount = count($_FILES['files']['name']); }  whereas in for loop you are using { $_FILES['filee']['name'] }

Comment: count image like this $filesCount = count($_FILES['filee']['name']);

Comment: but it is the same code

Comment: add exit() after `$this->upload->display_errors()` and see if any of the uploads are failing...

Comment: also aren't you using dropzone (if I remember correctly from another question of yours)? personally I don't like to use `uploadMultiple` and instead only send one file per request but allow 3 simultaneous requests via `parallelUploads: 3` so each file is sent in a seperate request. I find this easier to (a) deal with errors as they occur (b) keep the upload code simple (c) reduce script execution time

Answer (score 0):

remove `for` loop and add `foreach`

```
$i = 0;
foreach($_FILES['files']['name'] as $row){
    $_FILES['filee']['name'] = $_FILES['files']['name'][$i];
    $_FILES['filee']['type'] = $_FILES['files']['type'][$i];
    $_FILES['filee']['tmp_name'] = $_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$i];
    $_FILES['filee']['error'] = $_FILES['files']['error'][$i];
    $_FILES['filee']['size'] = $_FILES['files']['size'][$i];
    if (!$this->upload->do_upload('filee')) {
        // $this->output->set_status_header(500);
        $this->output->set_output(strip_tags($this->upload->display_errors()));
    } else {
        $fileData = $this->upload->data();
        $manyimages = $fileData['file_name'];
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Comment: it gives the same result